# Spin direction of the electromagnetic field tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I guess the electromagnetic field strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ can be considered as a spin-1 field. So, is it possible to derive $F_{\mu\nu}$'s spin direction based on the elements in the tensor (the $\mu,\nu$ components)?

Answer (score 1):

The spin of a field can be derived using Noether's theorem for rotational symmetry, the spin density being the part of the conserved current when the momentum is 0.

For a rotational symmetry of the form

\begin{eqnarray}
\delta x^\nu &\rightarrow& \Delta\omega_{\mu\nu} x^\nu\\
\Delta \phi^\rho &\rightarrow& \frac{1}{2} \Delta\omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}_{\rho\sigma} \phi^\sigma
\end{eqnarray}

With $\omega$ a rotation tensor and $S$ depending on the type of field rotated, then the conserved current is

\begin{eqnarray}
J^{ij} = \int d^3x \{ (x^i T^{0j} - x^j T^{0i}) + \pi^{r} S^{ij}_{rs} \phi^s\}
\end{eqnarray}

The spin being simply

\begin{eqnarray}
S^{ij} = \int d^3x \  \pi^{\rho} S^{ij}_{\rho\sigma} \phi^\sigma
\end{eqnarray}

For a vector field,

\begin{eqnarray}
S^{\mu\nu}_{\rho\sigma} = \delta^\mu_\rho \delta^\nu_\sigma - \delta^\mu_\sigma \delta^\nu_\rho
\end{eqnarray}

And in the case of the EM field,

\begin{eqnarray}
\pi^{r} = - F^{0r}
\end{eqnarray}

Meaning that

\begin{eqnarray}
S^{ij} = \int d^3x \  F^{0j} A^{i} - F^{0i} A^{j}
\end{eqnarray}

Or in other words

\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{S} = \int d^3x \  \vec{E} \times \vec{A}
\end{eqnarray}

For a monochromatic wave going in the direction $z$, this means

\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{S} = \int d^3x \  (\pm \omega A_0^2 \vec \partial_z) = \int d^3x \  (\pm \frac{E}{\omega} \vec \partial_z)
\end{eqnarray}

Which, once quanticized, means that $\frac{E}{\omega} = \hbar$, which is indeed what we expect for a photon spin.

Comment: There must be a typo in the second equation, the free indices of the right hand and left-hand side do not match (lhs: upper $\rho$, rhs: lower $\rho$).

Comment: Thanks for the response! But what could be said about the spin direction of any general anti-symmetric spin-1 field $B_{\mu\nu}$ ?

Comment: This spin expression is not gauge invariant, which makes sense since there is no such thing as gauge invariant electromagnetic spin.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as the spin of the electromagnetic field tensor. In fact there is no spin at all in gauge invariant electromagnetism. There is only the total angular momentum ${\bf J} = {\bf r} \times {\bf P} \,,$ where ${\bf P}$ is the Poynting vector.

Comment: I guess this refers to gauge invariant *classical* electromagnetism?

Comment: @Andrew Can you give me an expression of photon spin that is gauge invariant?

Comment: Let's say you are computing scattering amplitudes in QED, and your "in" state has an incoming photon with a definite helicity. The helicity of this photon is gauge invariant.