# Non-gauge-invariance of EM angular momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauge-invariance

In 16.7 b) of Zangwill we're asked to show that the expression
$$
{\bf L}=\epsilon_o\int d^3r E_k ({\bf r}\times\nabla)A_k
+ \epsilon_o\int d^3r {\bf E} \times {\bf A} 
$$
is not gauge invariant. Substituting ${\bf A}\to{\bf A} + \nabla f$ gives
$$
{\bf L} \to {\bf L} + \epsilon_o\int d^3r E_k ({\bf r}\times\nabla)(\nabla f)_k
+ \epsilon_o\int d^3r {\bf E} \times ({\nabla f})
$$
How do I show that the additional term is non-vanishing?

Comment: Might this question help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210195/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by giving an example. For example taking $\chi=5x$ will do the job. Taking $\chi$ equal to the density of a hypothetical elephant running at 50 times the speed of light is also a good choice. It illustrates the absurdity of gauge invariance at the same time.